# Custom permission in Android

Tags: android, permissions

I'm trying to figure out how to work with custom permissions in Android.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms .

I found similar problems answered here but none of the answers worked for me...
I've created simple app with Android studio 2.1.1

```
package com.example.lukas.permtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

with manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lukas.permtest">

    <permission android:name="com.example.lukas.permission.ACTIVITY_PERM"
        android:label="@string/permlab_activity"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_activity"
        android:protectionLevel="normal"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.lukas.permission.ACTIVITY_PERM"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"

            android:permission="com.example.lukas.permission.ACTIVITY_PERM">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have Sony Xperia Z2 tablet with Andoid 4.4.2 and Xperia Z3+ With Android 6.0
The app doesn't work. I get the same exception for both devices...

```
W/ActivityManager: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.lukas.permtest/.MainActivity } from ProcessRecord{44cf1178 2461:com.sonyericsson.home/u0a95} (pid=2461, uid=10095) requires com.example.lukas.permission.ACTIVITY_PERM
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah!  That's pretty funny!

I believe that what is going on here is that, although you've done everything right as far as your process and the permission, you forgot one small thing...

The Launcher needs to start your app.  The Launcher doesn't have your custom permission.

In other words, *your* application could launch its own `MainActivity`, because it has the permission to do so.  The Launcher does not have the permission, so when it attempts to launch the `android.intent.action.MAIN` Activity, if fails for lack of permission.

Separate the Main Activity from the Activity protected by the permission.  Launch the protected Activity from the Main Activity and everything go smooth as silk.